# MongoDb, how return specifics items in strings array?

Tags: arrays, string, mongodb

I'm new in mongo's world, and i've a trouble.

```
[
    {
        "name" :"name 1",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "clientId" : 1,
                "groups" : [
                    "group 1",
                    "group 2",
                    "group 3",
                ]
            },
            {
                "clientId" : 2,
                "groups" : [
                    "group 1"
                ]
            }
        ]

    }
]
```

I have two filters **clientId** and **groups**

If i send:

- clientId :  1
- groups :  ['group 1', 'group 2']

I need to return the item with array but only the items that are inside like:

```
[
    {
        "name" :"name 1",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "clientId" : 1,
                "groups" : [
                    "group 1",
                    "group 2",
                ]
            }
        ]

    }
]
```

I'm using $in inside groups, but it alwas return all items of array

I don't know how do it, something like $elemMatch but for strings array ?

Any idea ??

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use `$elemMatch` as below :

```
db.collection.find({"roles":{"$elemMatch":{"clientId":1,"groups":{"$in":["group 1", "group 2"]}}}},{"roles.$":1,"name":1}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to get the desired document. The following aggregation pipeline makes use of the **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator as the first stage to filter the documents from the collection going into the pipeline. The next couple of pipeline stages are **[`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operators that deconstructs the array fields from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document replaces the array with an element value.

A further **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline is required to then filter the documents from the deconstructed arrays.

The next **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline steps group input documents by the `_id` expression and applies the accumulator expression **[`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push)** to each group to preserve the original array fields:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "roles.clientId": 1,
            "roles.groups": { "$in": ["group 1", "group 2"] }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$roles" },
    { "$unwind": "$roles.groups" },
    {
        "$match": {
            "roles.clientId": 1,
            "roles.groups": { "$in": ["group 1", "group 2"] }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "groups": { "$push": "$roles.groups" },
            "clientId": { "$first": "$roles.clientId" }
        } 
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "roles": { 
                "$push": {
                    "groups": "$groups",
                    "clientId": "$clientId" 
                }
            }
        } 
    }
])
```

**Output**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("55885ce782b3e628fee8c63b"),
            "roles" : [ 
                {
                    "groups" : [ 
                        "group 1", 
                        "group 2"
                    ],
                    "clientId" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```